# Why is max-height not hiding my content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown nav bar with some subtle transitions. I can't use `height:0 > height:auto` to hide the content because it just doesn't work with transitions. I tried using `max-height:0 > max-height:5000px` but it seems that the content is actually still there just hidden by the `opacity`. This creates an issue because when you hover over the "invisible" content it shows up even if it's not actually supposed to.

Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/ajrdesign/pen/cabGx

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="">Products
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Some</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Solutions</a></li>
  <li><a href="">More</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  display:inline-block;
}
.has-dropdown{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content{
    opacity:0;
    max-height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 350ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 350ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 350ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 350ms;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 350ms;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.has-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 5000px;
}
```

What's the hang up? Why isn't `max-height:0` actually working like it should be?

Comment: Have you considered using `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: This will prevent the sub menu from fading out again as it will hide immediately on mouse leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can solve it: The idea is to toggle the visibility of the element and fade it in. When reversing this, on mouse leave, the sub menu gets faded out and the visibility is set to hidden again but this time with a delay, so that it takes place after the element has finished fading out:

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;        
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0.35s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0.55s linear;
}

.has-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.2s 0.35s ease-in-out, visibility 0s 0s linear;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyeqH)